# Make jQuery droppable scroll when onHover event happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have a container for lots of divs and I don't know how many child elements it'll have on load.

It is a droppable area and I want to make it scroll to show hidden child content whenever a user hovers a draggable at the top of/bottom of the container.

I am using jquery ui draggables and droppables and will appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I did; thanks all the same; I got it fixed.

Comment: AbdulFattah, could you post your solution? ( I realize this is an old thread! )